# flex/air how to load a class that is on another module

Tags: apache-flex, api, air, module, classloader

I´m trying to build my flex modular app, and got the following scenario

Portal (which includes, 2 modules:)
   -Mod1 (.swf)
   -Mod2 (.swf)

Also, i have Mod1-API (.swc)

The Mod1-API, defines interfaces which are implemented on the Mod1 (.swf).
Both the Mod1 and Mod2 swfs import the Mod1-API swc.

I´m trying to call the API method on the Mod2. On Mod2 I´ve the interface, since it is shared via the Mod1-API project.

What I´m trying to achieve is the real implementation class loading on Mod2, via reflection, using the getDefinitionByName method, but it says its not defined.

So, is there a way to achieve it?

I mean, how from the mod2 load a class that is on the Mod1 project, returning just the interfacce to the mod2 so it can call methods just like an ordinary API method?

Comment: didn't understand your question, are you looking for something like eval function? to call API method which you have in a String format during runtime? And please share some piece of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you are loading your class definitions. Flex uses both Security Domains and Application Domains to partition code which has been loaded.

If you want Module 2 to access code loaded via Module 1, they need to be loaded into both the same security and application domains.

[This](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSd75bf4610ec9e22f43855da312214da1d8f-8000.html) should give you a good start.